# Makefile on GCC for C

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I'm using MinGW and trying to create a justify executable using the Makefile but it gives me the following error:

```
 Directory of C:\Users\PATTY\Desktop\loops

08/19/2016  01:34 PM    <DIR>          .
08/19/2016  01:34 PM    <DIR>          ..
08/18/2016  10:41 PM            59,628 a.exe
08/18/2016  11:58 PM               261 demo.c
08/18/2016  11:59 PM            59,541 demo.exe
08/18/2016  07:01 PM               605 justify.c
08/18/2016  07:01 PM             1,122 line.c
08/18/2016  07:02 PM               197 line.h
08/19/2016  01:03 AM               350 newquote.txt
08/18/2016  11:05 PM               628 planets.c
08/18/2016  11:14 PM            60,139 planets.exe
07/15/2016  08:03 PM                89 pun.c
08/19/2016  12:55 AM               412 quote.txt
08/13/2016  05:32 PM               167 reverse.c
08/18/2016  10:45 PM            28,107 reverse.exe
08/18/2016  10:45 PM               708 reverse.o
08/19/2016  03:14 AM               459 something.txt
08/11/2016  11:14 PM             1,698 test.c
08/18/2016  07:01 PM               427 word.c
08/18/2016  07:02 PM                92 word.h
              18 File(s)        214,630 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  164,884,508,672 bytes free

C:\Users\PATTY\Desktop\loops>mingw32-make justify
cc     justify.c   -o justify
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, cc justify.c -o justify, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
<builtin>: recipe for target 'justify' failed
mingw32-make: *** [justify] Error 2

C:\Users\PATTY\Desktop\loops>
```

I'm a beginner when it comes to this so please let me know what am I missing or doing wrong.

Edit:

Another failed attempt:

```
C:\Users\PATTY\Desktop\loops>mingw32-make justify CC=gcc
gcc     justify.c   -o justify
C:\Users\PATTY\AppData\Local\Temp\cc2z2lvl.o:justify.c:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `clear_line'
C:\Users\PATTY\AppData\Local\Temp\cc2z2lvl.o:justify.c:(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `read_word'
C:\Users\PATTY\AppData\Local\Temp\cc2z2lvl.o:justify.c:(.text+0x40): undefined reference to `flush_line'
C:\Users\PATTY\AppData\Local\Temp\cc2z2lvl.o:justify.c:(.text+0x5f): undefined reference to `space_remainding'
C:\Users\PATTY\AppData\Local\Temp\cc2z2lvl.o:justify.c:(.text+0x68): undefined reference to `write_line'
C:\Users\PATTY\AppData\Local\Temp\cc2z2lvl.o:justify.c:(.text+0x6d): undefined reference to `clear_line'
C:\Users\PATTY\AppData\Local\Temp\cc2z2lvl.o:justify.c:(.text+0x79): undefined reference to `add_word'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
<builtin>: recipe for target 'justify' failed
mingw32-make: *** [justify] Error 1

C:\Users\PATTY\Desktop\loops>
```

Comment: Pictures of problems are useless. Your code and the error messages are text. Cut/paste them into your question.

Comment: I just don't know how to copy/paste text printed on the cmd prompt

Comment: Add the folder containing mingw-make.exe to your Path environment variable, close the terminal, open it again and retry.

Comment: The "Getting started" page on MinGW website mentions that the Path is not modified during the installation, you have to do it yourself. Here WIndows simply can't find mingw-make.exe.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to do it

Comment: Please, post your Makefile contents as well.

Comment: Just to clarify, I already had set the path for mingw32 before, but you're saying that I need to do the same for the mingw-make.exe right?

Comment: it may not be able to find cc.exe on the path

Comment: Yes it seems that the command that fails is the call to the compiler, not make. cc is not correctly expanded to the compiler name. Please show the Makefile

Comment: Superficially, you should run `mingw32-make justify CC=gcc` to run `gcc` instead of `cc`.  I'm not sure it's actually that easy.

Comment: TimF I had been using the gcc and everything else works (compiling c code) but just the make command isn't working.

Comment: I tried that command Jonathan, it's still giving me errors. I uploaded the picture in the main post.

Comment: @tadm123 You can copy and paste from cmd by right clicking and select `Mark`. Make your selection and then press `Enter` to copy it to your clipboard.

Comment: If you don't post the Makefile we can't help you.

Comment: Dumb question, but how can I post the Makefile?

Comment: Uh, well find it, copy its content and paste it in your question.  Add 4 spaces on the left of every line to put it in the code snippet.

Comment: I don't see a makefile in your directory, nor are you specifying one with the `-f` flag, how is that even working?? Anyway, for your second failed attempt, looks like you aren't linking in a needed library or object file (or failing to compile a necessary source file). Where are the functions `clear_line`, `read_word`, etc? They must not be in `justify.c`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm using MinGW and trying to create a justify executable using the Makefile

No you're not. The make command:

```
C:\Users\PATTY\Desktop\loops>mingw32-make justify
```

doesn't specify any makefile. In that case, `make` will look by default
for `makefile` in the working directory, and failing that will look for
`Makefile` in the working directory. But the directory listing of `C:\Users\PATTY\Desktop\loops`
shows that neither of those makefiles exists either.

In that case, `make` falls back on its built-in rules database to see
if any of them might let it build the target `justify` from files that
exist in the working directory, in the absence of any specified or default makefile.

It finds this built-in rule:

```
%: %.c
    $(LINK.c) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@
```

which will attempt to compile and link a target matching `%` from a single
matching C source file `%.c`.

This rule matches for target `justify` and source file `justify.c`. And that
source file exists in the working directory, so `make` tries the recipe:

```
    $(LINK.c) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@
```

with prerequisite `$^` = `justify.c` and target `$@` = `justify`

But it does not work because after full expansion of the variables, the recipe becomes:

```
cc     justify.c   -o justify
```

where `cc` is the default value of the make variable `CC`, denoting the C compiler.
That is because `$(LINK.c)` is defined:

```
LINK.c = $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH)
```

You have no such program as `cc` in your `PATH`, so the recipe fails:

```
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, cc justify.c -o justify, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
```

You realize this is the nature of the problem and you try:

```
C:\Users\PATTY\Desktop\loops>mingw32-make justify CC=gcc
```

There *is* such a program as `gcc` in your `PATH`, and it is your C compiler.
That's better, but the built-in recipe now expands to:

```
gcc     justify.c   -o justify
```

which attempts to compile and link your program `justify` from the single
source file `justify.c`. And as [you know](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39009571/1362568),
the recipe you require to build this program in this directory is:

```
gcc -o justify justify.c line.c word.c
```

So the recipe you are running now fails with the linkage errors you have observed because
you are not compiling or linking the source files in which the missing functions are
defined.

If you want to build the program correctly using `make`, you will need to learn
the essentials of writing makefiles and then write one that instructs `make` to build
the program correctly. You can save this makefile in `C:\Users\PATTY\Desktop\loops`
as either `makefile` or `Makefile` and `make` will use it by default. Or you can
call it whatever you like, and specify it by name with the `-f` option when you invoke `make`:

```
mingw32-make -f whatever.mak ...
```

[Here is a fairly sound beginner's tutorial for using GCC with GNU make](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/gcc_make.html).
For authoritative documentation, [here is the GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/) and
[here is the GNU Make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html)